# Update only new records sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table 1 :

```
ID    Name   Number
1    James    2344
```

If i write

`Update Table(Name,Number) set Name = "James", Number = "11111"`

Now Name = James remains the same and number is new... but when trigger is geared up it shows all fields as updated.

Comment: I want to update only the fields that is new.. is there any way to check this in SQL

Comment: What do you mean by new rows? How are you identifying new rows?

Comment: that is a tricky task - you have to check if the field has changed before update

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET Number = 11111
WHERE Name = 'James'
```

you should have a `WHERE` clause condition so only `James` will be updated.

Comment: No I mean I have a scenario where i am updating a GRID with a single checkbox and i wanted to know which field is only updated...
And I have to use a update statement with all the fields but all fields doesnt have new values ... did u got me ?

Comment: Then you need keys for all checked gridrows to update rows, get DataKeyNames value for all checked rows and update data.

Answer (score 0):

as if i understand you will check first the table if the data exist and if its same or not.
but if you make `UPDATE` for all it will be same , if user name is `TIM` and when `UPDATE` it will be same `TIM` just to run only one sql to to check first .

your update looks wrong

try do this

```
   UPDATE tablename SET number = 11111, SET name = 'James' WHERE ID = 1
```

like that it will update `number` but name will stay `James`

- the `UPDATE` will update only changed values

EDIT:
its gona be select before insert.

I think it's worth changing - but probably not worth doing a select before insert.

Comment: But when u have a trigger on that ... you will get both the fields as updated in Inserted like this

if update(StudentName) 'checking in trigger

Comment: why are you posting php answer in asp.net/sql question? Can you explain your answer in asp.net